# Is it possible to add title to toolbar button, declared as UIBarButtonSystemItem

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, toolbar, title

I'd like to set some buttons in my navigation toolbar and, for users not be confused of what each button do, I'd like to add title to each button, displayed under it. Is it possible to do this?

Declaration of button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *changeFiltersButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshButton)] autorelease];
```

``...

```
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexible,
                           changeFiltersButton, flexible, flexible,
                           refreshFiltersList, flexible, flexible,
                           more, flexible, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use images with name like the fallowing example

```
    NSMutableArray *toolBaritems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [toolBaritems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]];
    [toolBaritems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refresh)]];
    [toolBaritems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]];
    [toolBaritems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(change)]];

    [toolbar setItems:toolBaritems animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you! So I should simply create an image with text in it?  That makes sense...but I won't be able to edit titles without editing the whole image :(